# adding child entry in bidirectional one to one relation in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am new to spring jpa and learning about entity relation OneToOne bidirectional

I have created these two entities

Account.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String password;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Employee employee;
}
```

Employee.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "employee")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Account account;
}
```

Account Service where i am saving Account entity

```
public ResponseEntity<?> addAccount( Account account) {
        try {
            Account response = accountDAO.save(account);
    
            if (response != null) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(response);
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).build();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

while in Employee Service i am saving employee

```
private ResponseEntity<?> addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        try {
            Employee response = employeeDAO.save(employee);
            if (response != null) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(response);
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).build();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

when i am adding account with following json i am able to add employee and its reference in account

```
{
    "id": 1001,
    "password": "Amit47@123",
    "employee": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Amit Kumar",
        "email": "Amit@Naskay.in"
    }
}
```

checking it in database

```
mysql> select * from account;
+------+------------+-------------+
| id   | password   | employee_id |
+------+------------+-------------+
| 1001 | Amit47@123 |           1 |
+------+------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from employee;
+----+----------------+------------+
| id | email          | name       |
+----+----------------+------------+
|  1 | Amit@Naskay.in | Amit Kumar |
+----+----------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

but when i try to add Employee with following json

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Amit Kumar",
        "email": "Amit@Naskay.in",
        "account":{
    "id": 1002,
    "password": "Amit47@123"
    }
}
```

and checked in database

```
mysql> select * from account;
+------+------------+-------------+
| id   | password   | employee_id |
+------+------------+-------------+
| 1001 | Amit47@123 |           1 |
| 1002 | Amit47@123 |        NULL |
+------+------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from employee;
+----+----------------+------------+
| id | email          | name       |
+----+----------------+------------+
|  1 | Amit@Naskay.in | Amit Kumar |
|  2 | Amit@Naskay.in | Amit Kumar |
+----+----------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

which is not expected as employee_id for account 1002 is null , i was expecting that since our relation is bidirectional one to one it should update the employee_id to 2 for account 1002 when saving the entity in database.Please help me understand how bidirectional relation works

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more annotation to your `Employee` class to `Account` field
Something like this:

```
@JoinColumn (name="account")
```

One more think for your knowledge:

**One to one represents that a single entity is associated with a single instance of the other entity. An instance of a source entity can be at most mapped to one instance of the target entity.**

**UPDATED**

Entities mapping will look so:

```
Account

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "account")
    private Employee employee;

Employee 

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   private Account account;
```

**UPDATE**

For more details check this article it`s really good one it will help you,
[Vlad Mihalcea: onetoone-relationship](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

**UPDATE**

For more details how you can do it: read **module(3.17-18)** from official hibernate guide

[One-to-one](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html)

Comment: I have tried your solution ,but still getting the same response

Comment: To `Account` also add attribute `mappedBy="employee"` for field Employee and for Employee class  mappedBy attribute value please replace with "account"

Comment: if we add attribute mappedBy ="employee" for field employee in class account ,it is searching for employee attribute in table employee which does not exist.
Association 'com.example.examDummy.models.Account.employee' is 'mappedBy' a property named 'employee' which does not exist in the target entity type 'com.example.examDummy.models.Employee'

Comment: just a moment, i'm going to try this one and will give you an feedback, i will update my answer

Comment: mysql> select * from account;
+------+------------+
| id   | password   |
+------+------------+
| 1001 | Amit47@123 |
| 1002 | Amit47@123 |
+------+------------+


mysql> select * from employee;
+----+----------------+------------+------------+
| id | email          | name       | account_id |
+----+----------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Amit@Naskay.in | Amit Kumar |       1001 |
|  2 | Amit@Naskay.in | Amit Kumar |       NULL |
+----+----------------+------------+------------+

still getting the same response ,but in this case while adding account

Comment: @JoinColumn indicates that this entity is the owner of the relationship, that the corresponding table has a column with a foreign key to the referenced table. It's the reason why you take this kind of result.

Comment: so we can't add entity from both direction ??

Comment: @AmitBhatiwal i just update my answer with reference to official hibernate docs check module 3.17/18